# Adding subcollection into mongodb to an existing document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hey when i was using firebase it was kind of easy to update or add a subcollection , but its confusing in mongodb ! i see people adding  arrays instead of subcollection but what if i want to add an element to that existing array ! how can it be done , or how to add something like subcollection !
here is my example !
Model :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passwordHash: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  street: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  apartment: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
});

exports.User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

I want to add a notification collection or document to this User model whenever he recieves one ? i want the notifications to be a collection with documents referring the each notification ! but i didn't know how to do it !

Comment: It must be confusing because there are no subcollections in mongo.

Comment: what about subdocuments

Comment: There subdocuments, but it's just an array within the document, either embedded, or referenced. In any case it has no collection methods, only array operators.